# JLabels are invisible in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, grid-layout

I made a `JFrame` where I add a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`. The grid consists of `JLabel` components with a custom number in it. I have no Exception in the program. My problem is that the panel is visible on the `JFrame` (`mainFrame`), but you can't see the numbers of the labels that are added to the panel.

Can anybody tell me why I only see the panel, but not the labels?

First I create the GUI:

```
public Gui() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    mainFrame.setLayout(null);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Then I run this method:

```
public void startGame(Map map) {
    //Deletes every component that could be on the JFrame
    loescheAlles();

    //In the test are 100 paths in the String
    String[] paths = map.getPaths();
    //width has the value 1000
    int width = map.getBreite()*100;
    //height has the value 1000
    int height = map.getHoehe()*100;

    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setBounds(0,0,width,height);
    gamePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,height));

    JLabel[] label = new JLabel[paths.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<paths.length; i++) {
        //Text and border are not visible???
        label[i] = new JLabel("" + i);
        label[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        gamePanel.add(label[i]);
    }

    //Because I can see the Border on the JFrame I know, that the JPanel is visible.
    gamePanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    mainFrame.add(gamePanel);
}
```

Comment: `GridLayout` constructor takes as arguments the logical rows and columns of the grid (not the pixel dimensions).

Comment: First thing, remove `mainFrame.setLayout(null);`. If that does not work, [edit] to add a [mre],